# 2-approximation algorithm for Minimum Maximal Matching (MMM) problem

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, approximation-algorithms, matching-theory

I'm looking to find a 2-approximation algorithm (pseudocode) for the minimum maximal matching problem. I tried to find one but I did not manage. I want to use it to implement a program in java. Can anyone help in finding pseudocode for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easy $2$-approximation algorithm for finding a minimum size maximal matching.  Simply find *any* maximal matching.  Note that a maximal matching $M$ can be found greedily.  Initialize $M=\emptyset$.  Add any edge $xy$ to $M$, and in $G -x-y$ search for another edge to add and recurse.

Let $m$ be the size of a minimum maximal matching.  To show that this is a $2$-approximation, we must check that for every maximal matching $M$, $|M| \leq 2m$.  To see this let $V(M)$ be the vertices covered by $M$. Every minimum maximal matching $M_0$ must cover at least half the vertices of $V(M)$, otherwise we can extend $M_0$ via an edge in $M$.